# CVE-2023-23415 doesn't work on my Windows 10

Tags: networking, ping, icmp

The problem is that I am trying to find answers to the CVE-2023-23415 because it's not working.

So, I did everything correctly, I crafted an ICMP echo packet on Scapy, configured it to buffer overflow the implementation of ICMP on my host Windows 10 home, but still, nothing happens, the command was to open calculator (Here's the code of the Python script for Scapy)

```
from scapy.all import *

ip = IP(dst="target_ip")
icmp = ICMP(type=8, code=0)
payload = "cmd.exe /c calc.exe"  # payload for RCE

packet = ip/icmp/payload
send(packet)
```

And the command used on Scapy

```
icmp_pkt = IP(dst="TARGET_IP")/ICMP()/("A" * 1024)
```

```
send(icmp_pkt)
```

Comment: The question is not clear: you're stating a *vulnerability* does not *work*??

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that is my assumption. They want to test the exploit to run a program of their choice on another machine on their network. Only problem is that the exploit was announced and then immediately patched per the Microsoft article in my answer so the window for actually using the exploit was probably limited to a couple of days in March. Only people who have disabled Windows update are likely to be vulnerable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2023-23415) at Microsoft the vulnerability was disclosed in March 2023 and then patched in the March monthly roll up patches.

Unless you have a severely out of date system with Windows updates disabled you are unlikely to be able to exploit the vulnerability.

Comment: Alright got it, thanks

Comment: But one question, why does it happen tho? Like is it because the network stack doesn't properly check the input of the ICMP packet, and therefore it leads to a buffer overflow?

Comment: @AndyCrypto something along those lines. I can't find much in the way of specifics but there seems to be a paywalled article at https://doublepulsar.com/a-look-at-cve-2023-23415-a-windows-icmp-vulnerability-mitigations-which-is-not-a-cyber-meltdown-78a9f7e3e538

Comment: Also another question, is there any info on what has been done to patch it?